# Ubuntu 18.04. GNOME how to improve batter consumption?

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery

I have been for at least five years a happy Lubuntu user using it as my main OS, but I decided last weekend to switch my laptop to Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 GNOME. I did a minimal Ubuntu install using defaults.

However, GNOME consumes by laptop battery much faster. I can now practically see the percentage of battery going down. I get at least 1hrs or so less with Ubuntu 18.04 than with Lubuntu 18.04 on same laptop.

The only thing I can trace is the CPU usage by gnome-shell, not much, but it adds up. I see 2% or 3% CPU use every few seconds from gnome-shell even if I am doing nothing. I have no extensions that may need periodic refresh (such as CPU indicators), have disabled animations, lowered display brightness, and installed tlp with default config (I was using tlp also in Lubuntu).

Any idea how to improve battery life in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME? Any processes or services I can kill?